# Downsampling then upsampling raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to downsample a raster then upsample it again.

I am using the gdalwarp function in QGIS.

When downsampling the raster looks OK in the front end, I set the cell size to 10x the original raster.

When upsampling back to the original cell size using the downsampled raster the original data seems to be preserved and I end up back at the original raster. What I'm expecting to happen is that I see blocks of 10x10 cells all with the same value (same as the downsampled raster).

Does QGIS preserve the original cell values?

Is there a way to perform this operation?

Comment: If you save the downsampled result into a new file with a new name and upsample that it would be a miracle if QGIS can find new details to the image.

Comment: Why use gdalwarp?
Use for example the SAGA/Grid-Tools: resampling.
This works fine.

Comment: Why not? gdalwarp should work just as fine, or gdal_translate with -tr parameter.

Comment: If you use the nearest neighbour resampling method this should indeed work - and on my machine it does. Did you make sure to not accidentaly select the original raster as input in the dropdown menu when upscaling? Could you provide a small sample dataset so we can reproduce this error?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS' [Block Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Block_Statistics/009z000000qp000000/).

Comment: Still not found an answer to this. It seems ot be because QGIS preserves the original high resolution data in the downsampled file. Therefore when upsampling we just go back to the original.

Comment: gdal_translate seems to have the same issue as gdalwarp.

Comment: Block statistic is exactly what i want to do...

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this fits your problem, I've found that `r.resamp.stats` functions the same as ArcGIS's block statistics

I just used it to calculate the mode of 5x5 cell blocks

Have a play around with that

[image: Block statistics is really handy for determining things such as mean and mode]